# sendMessage() of react-native-firebase/messaging doesn't work in version 6.2.0

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have used react-native-firebase version 6.2.0

When I use react-native-firebase/messaging, I found out any sendMessage() function doesn’t work.
(I use android devices and virtual machine.)

I just follow the document [here](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging/reference/module)

- At first, I registered remoteNotification and got FCM token from it. => init()
- Then, I sent upstream remoteMessage => sendMessage()
- But, I could not find out where are the messages. => could not receive any messages in device and in firebase cloud messaging console.
- When I sent messages from firebase cloud messaging console, I could got the message at devices.

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import store from 'project3/redux/store.js';


export async function init() {
  const enabled = await messaging().hasPermission();
  if (enabled) {
    console.log('user has permissions');
  } else {
    console.log('user doesnt have permission');
    const enabled2 = await messaging().requestPermission();
    if (enabled2) {
      console.log('requestPermission');
    } else {
      console.log('not requestPermission');
    }
  }
  console.log('getToken');
  await messaging().registerForRemoteNotifications();
  const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  const uid = store.getState().email;
  console.log('fmcToken : ' + fcmToken);

  await firestore()
    .doc(`users/${uid}`)
    .update({
      fcmToken: fcmToken,
    });

  console.log(
    'isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications ' +
      messaging().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications,
  );
  messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
    console.log('FCM Message Data:', remoteMessage.data);
  });

  messaging().onSendError(event => {
    console.log(event.messageId);
    console.log(event.error);
  });
}

export async function sendMessage() {
  console.log('sendMessage');
  await messaging()
    .sendMessage({
      data: {
        loggedIn: Date.now().toString(),
        uid: store.getState().email,
      },
    })
    .then(msg => {
      console.log(msg);
    });
}
```

Please help me. 
I found many cases about below version 5.x.x of react-native-firebase.
But, there are very few cases about 6.x.x and [guide](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/messaging/reference/module) isn't also sufficient.
You may save my weeks.

Comment: sorry, i dont know the answer to it , but can you help me how you achieved recieving notifications while app  in foregorund .

Comment: hi. I just installed react-native-firebase/messaging and do the init() function I wrote upper. Then, I wrote the message in the firebase cloud messaging console. Then, I got the message from device.

Comment: yeah, message pushing is okay. i just need like what and where are you implemnting init function si that it always listen to any push notification

Comment: and which package did you add for firebase notifications?

Comment: for messaging, I added react-native-firebase/messaging v6.2.0, And I called the init function I wrote in the App.js that is up at the initial time of application. (for notification, I added react-native-notification package. but I didn't use it at here)

Comment: I think it should use [headlees js](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) right?